# How to get an element in soup.find_all after find out some class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get a tome stamp

```
timestamp_containers = page_soup.findAll("p", {"class":"tagline"})
```

And the output is

```
<p class="tagline ">submitted <time class="live-timestamp" datetime="2018-10-06T10:02:28+00:00" title="Sat Oct 6 10:02:28 2018 UTC">1 month ago</time> by <a class="author may-blank id-t2_4r97b5o" href="https://old.reddit.com/user/Lord_Mop">Lord_Mop</a><span class="userattrs"></span><span class="gilding-bar" data-subredditpath="/r/assassinscreed/"></span></p>
```

I want to get a specific element `" title="Sat Oct 6 10:02:28 2018 UTC"`
But when I try

```
for eeee in timestamp_containers[0].time:
if eeee == " title":
    continue
print(eeee)
```

It failed. How do I get `title` in `timestamp_containers[0].time`?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = timestamp_containers[0].find('time').get('title')
```

looking at my output below, is this what you're needing?

```
In [10]: print (data)
Sat Oct 6 10:02:28 2018 UTC
```